# In a React 18.2.0 component after logout state is not changing

Tags: reactjs

I am new at react development. I am fetching issue after log out.
I have written logout handler and related code.

```
  // other codes
   const navigate = useNavigate(); 
   const auth = useAuth();
   let user = auth.currentUser;
   function handleLogout(){
      auth.logout();
      navigate("/");
  }
 //render code
 return (
      <Nav>
       //other code
         <p>Welcome, {user.name}</p>
        <Nav.Link onClick={handleLogout}> Logout</Nav.Link>
       //other code 
     </Nav>
 )
```

**Problem is from other pages without home page("/") logout handler unable to reset user to null as a result always seeing user name even after logout until manually reload page.**

Comment: If component is unmounted it's state is deleted

Comment: Where is `useAuth` coming from? Is it from the [`react-use-auth`](//useauth.dev) library? Did you use another library or did you write it yourself? Also there is no reason for `user` to be a state in the current scenario. You could simply do `const user = auth.currentUser;`

Comment: I have written myself.

Comment: In that case there is probably some state issue inside the `useAuth` hook. Could you provide the source of `useAuth`? Or at least the part that is relevant to signing out.

Comment: here is the authprovider code: https://gist.github.com/imran396/ca85b1088a2dc450d004080f3a42b6e5

Comment: Actually, the issue is probably that you manage half of the state in `useAuth` (signing in), and the other half of the state (signing out) in the current component. When signing out the `user` state is set to `null`, but `auth.currentUser` is never updated. So it might reset `user` back to whatever it was before.

Comment: yes @3limin4t0r I am agree with you. I will try to update current user after logout. Thanks

Comment: yes working even no state required that cases in current component just need to set auth.currentUser null for logout in useAuth hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you split the state into two parts. You have `auth.currentUser` that holds the signed in user. But you also have `user`, which shadows `auth.currentUser`. Whenever you sign out you update `user`, but `auth.currentUser` is never changed.

In your scenario this causes `user` to be set to `null` on sign out, but it's reset to whatever it was before by

```
useEffect(() => {
  setUser(auth.currentUser);
}, [auth.currentUser]);
```

---

You already have a `logout` callback exposed through `useAuth`. You just need it to clear `auth.currentUser` as well, not just clear the cookie. Then use this callback in your component.

```
// authProvider.jsx
// ...

const logout = async () => {
    deleteCookie('jwt');
    setCurrentUser(null); //<- add this line
}

// ...
```

Then in your component:

```
// other codes
const navigate = useNavigate(); 
const auth = useAuth();
const user = auth.currentUser; 
   
function handleLogout() {
    auth.logout();
    navigate("/");
}

return (
    <Nav>
        //other code
        <p>Welcome, {user.name}</p>
        <Nav.Link onClick={handleLogout}> Logout</Nav.Link>
        //other code
    </Nav>
);
```

If `user` is not instantly present you could wait for it to be present with `if (!user) return null;` which will hide the component as long as there is no `user`.